# Apache Sling JCR browser required

Tags: sling

I've just started learning sling. The biggest problem to me at this stage is to browse JCR repository. Is there any good tool to view what is inside repo, showing resources and all properties?

I need something like this one:
http://blogs.adobe.com/gary/files/2011/05/pic3.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sling does include a basic explorer that you can access at /.explorer.html

I haven't followed the status of the https://github.com/onflapp/RESTed explorer lately, but that looked quite interesting last time I looked: https://github.com/onflapp/RESTed

There's also http://www.jcrbrowser.org/sling/website/ which I haven't tried in a long time but might be worth looking at.

Comment: There's also https://github.com/jollyca/sling-explorer , which seems to be an updated fork of RESTed.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is [Composum](https://github.com/ist-dresden/composum), which describes itselfs as a 'Slingified' JCR browser.

[image: screenshot]]

Some of its additional features ( [complete list](https://github.com/ist-dresden/composum/wiki/Browser-Features) ) are:

- repository tree with configurable filters
- node creation / deletion / move / reorder
- property manipulation
- binary data upload / download
- component rendering and asset view
- template based queries with history
- JSON view, download and upload
- ACL view and manipulation

Answer (score 0):

I have a JCR Browser that is Open Source and on GitHub. It uses JQueryMobile and SpringBoot.

http://meta64.com